# What causes half downstream speed on gigabit interface?

Tags: networking, windows-10, internet, gigabit-ethernet, internet-speed

I have 2 computers, one is a Win 10 desktop, the other is a Win 7 Dell laptop. Both have an Intel gigabit network interface. The internet is symmetric gigabit. On dekstop, I measure **500**/900-ish speeds, fairly constant. On the latop I get around 900/700. I would like to get 900/900-ish speeds on the desktop, I'm fine with what the laptop is getting. The situation makes me assume that the connection itself is fine as it would get 900/900+, but the network interfaces or their setup hits a bottleneck.

**It works fine in Safe Mode!**

**I tried:**

- Switching the cables
- Changing the connected ports on the optical network terminal
- Setting from auto negotiate to 1gbps full duplex in the interface advanced options
- Turning off flow control and energy saving features
- Updating Windows 10
- Rebooting the ONT and the computers
- The test server is provided by the ISP, on speedtest.net (always using the same server, with "multi" connections mode)
- Nothing else is running on the network/computers
- Everything is directly connected to the ISP device with Cat5e cabels

How can I fix this? What else I can try? What other info would be useful?

**The iPerf3 tests as requested**

These were flowing through the ISP device, I didn't directly connect the 2 machines.

**Desktop is the client, laptop is the server:**

```
iperf3 -c 192.168.1.12 -n 2048M -l 32K
Connecting to host 192.168.1.12, port 5201
[  4] local 192.168.1.13 port 5791 connected to 192.168.1.12 port 5201
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]   0.00-1.00   sec   112 MBytes   938 Mbits/sec
[  4]   1.00-2.00   sec   112 MBytes   936 Mbits/sec
[  4]   2.00-3.00   sec   112 MBytes   938 Mbits/sec
[  4]   3.00-4.00   sec   112 MBytes   939 Mbits/sec
[  4]   4.00-5.00   sec   112 MBytes   939 Mbits/sec
[  4]   5.00-6.00   sec   112 MBytes   939 Mbits/sec
[  4]   6.00-7.00   sec   112 MBytes   941 Mbits/sec
[  4]   7.00-8.00   sec   112 MBytes   939 Mbits/sec
[  4]   8.00-9.00   sec   112 MBytes   939 Mbits/sec
[  4]   9.00-10.00  sec   112 MBytes   939 Mbits/sec
[  4]  10.00-11.00  sec   112 MBytes   941 Mbits/sec
[  4]  11.00-12.00  sec   111 MBytes   934 Mbits/sec
[  4]  12.00-13.00  sec   112 MBytes   940 Mbits/sec
[  4]  13.00-14.00  sec   112 MBytes   939 Mbits/sec
[  4]  14.00-15.00  sec   112 MBytes   940 Mbits/sec
[  4]  15.00-16.00  sec   112 MBytes   940 Mbits/sec
[  4]  16.00-17.00  sec   112 MBytes   938 Mbits/sec
[  4]  17.00-18.00  sec   111 MBytes   934 Mbits/sec
[  4]  18.00-18.31  sec  34.1 MBytes   931 Mbits/sec
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]   0.00-18.31  sec  2.00 GBytes   938 Mbits/sec                  sender
[  4]   0.00-18.31  sec  2.00 GBytes   938 Mbits/sec                  receiver
iperf Done.
```

**Laptop is the client, desktop is the server:**

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on 5201
-----------------------------------------------------------
Accepted connection from 192.168.1.12, port 49553
[  5] local 192.168.1.13 port 5201 connected to 192.168.1.12 port 49554
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  5]   0.00-1.00   sec  41.8 MBytes   351 Mbits/sec
[  5]   1.00-2.00   sec  58.6 MBytes   492 Mbits/sec
[  5]   2.00-3.00   sec  59.3 MBytes   498 Mbits/sec
[  5]   3.00-4.00   sec  62.6 MBytes   525 Mbits/sec
[  5]   4.00-5.00   sec  62.5 MBytes   525 Mbits/sec
[  5]   5.00-6.00   sec  59.5 MBytes   499 Mbits/sec
[  5]   6.00-7.00   sec  62.1 MBytes   521 Mbits/sec
[  5]   7.00-8.00   sec  64.1 MBytes   537 Mbits/sec
[  5]   8.00-9.00   sec  59.3 MBytes   498 Mbits/sec
[  5]   9.00-10.00  sec  59.9 MBytes   503 Mbits/sec
[  5]  10.00-11.00  sec  60.8 MBytes   510 Mbits/sec
[  5]  11.00-12.00  sec  64.0 MBytes   537 Mbits/sec
[  5]  12.00-13.00  sec  60.9 MBytes   511 Mbits/sec
[  5]  13.00-14.00  sec  59.6 MBytes   500 Mbits/sec
[  5]  14.00-15.00  sec  59.1 MBytes   496 Mbits/sec
[  5]  15.00-16.00  sec  61.3 MBytes   514 Mbits/sec
[  5]  16.00-17.00  sec  61.2 MBytes   513 Mbits/sec
[  5]  17.00-18.00  sec  59.8 MBytes   502 Mbits/sec
[  5]  18.00-19.00  sec  60.2 MBytes   505 Mbits/sec
[  5]  19.00-20.00  sec  59.6 MBytes   500 Mbits/sec
[  5]  20.00-21.00  sec  59.7 MBytes   501 Mbits/sec
[  5]  21.00-22.00  sec  60.2 MBytes   505 Mbits/sec
[  5]  22.00-23.00  sec  59.9 MBytes   503 Mbits/sec
[  5]  23.00-24.00  sec  60.6 MBytes   509 Mbits/sec
[  5]  24.00-25.00  sec  62.6 MBytes   525 Mbits/sec
[  5]  25.00-26.00  sec  62.3 MBytes   522 Mbits/sec
[  5]  26.00-27.00  sec  60.1 MBytes   505 Mbits/sec
[  5]  27.00-28.00  sec  59.6 MBytes   500 Mbits/sec
[  5]  28.00-29.00  sec  60.2 MBytes   505 Mbits/sec
[  5]  29.00-30.00  sec  61.3 MBytes   514 Mbits/sec
[  5]  30.00-31.00  sec  61.2 MBytes   513 Mbits/sec
[  5]  31.00-32.00  sec  60.4 MBytes   507 Mbits/sec
[  5]  32.00-33.00  sec  60.6 MBytes   508 Mbits/sec
[  5]  33.00-34.00  sec  59.9 MBytes   502 Mbits/sec
[  5]  34.00-34.05  sec  3.04 MBytes   520 Mbits/sec
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  5]   0.00-34.05  sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec                  sender
[  5]   0.00-34.05  sec  2.00 GBytes   505 Mbits/sec                  receiver
```

Comment: Can you measure with iperf3 _between_ desktop and laptop?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I just ran those tests you asked. Never used iPerf3 before, it's such a useful tool!

Comment: Do you also see that difference by taking the cable from your desktop and plugging it into your laptop? If it's the same it would be indicative to be an issue wiht the machine rather than the network components.

Comment: Changing around cables doesn't seem to have a pronounced effect, desktop to laptop is always faster than laptop to desktop. Even when directly connected.

Speeds between my 3rd laptop, connected also directly to the 2nd laptop, are 8-900 both ways with very little spread between values, that's beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

It was software-based. Networx software caused the issue while this option was selected -.- Now I measure ~950/950 and am very satisfied.

[image: Ignore local traffic within the LAN]